# MediaWiki: Show orphaned files

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to get a list of uploaded files which aren't linked at all.

Is there an equivalent of `Special:OrphanedPages` for files?

Or is there a filter for `Special:ListFiles` for orphans?

Or is there a SQL query which returns the file names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special page `Special:UnusedFiles` that shows all files that are not in use.